# Linqpad TypeLoadException while fetching schema information

Tags: datacontext, linqpad, connection-timeout, typeloadexception

I get the following error when trying to load a large db into linqpad.  I can connect to smaller dbs on the same server, but not this larger one.  This DB is a Dynamics GP database.  Not the actual DYNAMICS one, but the default 'TWO' one.

```
System.TypeLoadException
```

---

> Type "LINQPad.User.TypedDataContext' from assembly
>   'TypedDataContext_iuhmuv. Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral
>   PublicKeyToken=null'

contrain more methods than the current implementation allows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLR imposes a hard limit of `ushort.MaxValue - 15` methods per class. It's unlikely that any database would have more tables than this, but I have encountered databases with a ridiculous number of *stored procedures*. It is possible that your database has more than 65K stored procedures / functions?

If so, you can tell LINQPad not to create methods for them by editing the connection (right-click, Properties) and untick the 'Include Stored Procedures and Functions' checkbox.